# Not able to connect to AWS Redshift through Java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to connect to redshift, but I keep getting an error -

```
java.sql.SQLException: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:redshift://xxxx-redshift-xxxx.xxxx.xxxx-xxxxx.xxxx:xxxx/xxxxx
```

I am using the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, I have created the Maven repository and dependency as well set a class path for `redshift-jbdc42-1.2.1.10001. jar`